# Validating One of Two Choices

Tags: java, validation

This is working for "draw" but not for discard". I just want it to validate whether the input is one of the two. I run into this problem frequently and don't understand why. Does anyone see the problem?

```
while(!(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("draw") && !(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("discard"))))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to check if the input is one of the two, you want to do

```
while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("draw") || choice.equalsIgnoreCase("discard"))
```

Right now you're only entering the loop when `choice` is neither `"draw"` nor `"discard"`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close a parenthesis for the "draw" test, you could use

```
while (!(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("draw")) && 
       !(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("discard")))
```

or

```
while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("draw") && 
       !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("discard"))
```

or use [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) like

```
while (!(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("draw") || 
         choice.equalsIgnoreCase("discard")))
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I have done this so many times without finding a solution! I really appreciate it! (De Morgan's Laws...good old discrete math)

Comment: Waitaminute.  Do you want to see if *neither* of them are true, or do you want to see if *either* of them are true?  You've posted the latter in your question, but this answer does the former.

Comment: @Makoto I assume he's prompting for input again when it doesn't match. But clearly `(!(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("draw") && !(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("discard"))))` applies the negation to the negation of discard equality. And OP said it *works* for "draw".

Comment: I'm running the exact same expression, and I don't see the same behavior for "draw".  I'm not as convinced as you are that this is the correct approach, when I'm not sure if he wants one or the other type of validation to begin with - his words say one thing, but his code says another.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify it (and watch your parentheses in the future):

```
while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("draw") || choice.equalsIgnoreCase("discard")) {
    // code
}
```

What your code is currently doing is this:

```
!(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("draw") && !(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("discard")))
```

Pay close attention to that negation.  It's closing the *entire* expression, because you've opened up the paren too wide.  That would evaluate to `true` only if you entered in `"discard"`.

If you meant to say this:

```
!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("draw") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("discard"))
```

Then that contradicts what you're trying to evaluate - you want to check to see if one of those evaluates to `true`.  If you correct the parentheses, then it would still be incorrect, as it only evaluates if *both* of those statements are `false`.